# returning a two dimensional array from a function in vbscript

Tags: function, multidimensional-array, vbscript, return

im having an issue with a program im working on.
what im trying to do is have a function accept input from a user and store that data in an array
for small testing purposes it is a 3 x 3 array
i have gotten the array within the function to work as tested by echoing out all values stored.
however when i attempt to return the array to the sub from which it is called i get mismatch errors, im not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
    Sub SubroutineA()
          Dim Array(2,2)

          Array = GetInfo()

    End Sub

    Function GetInfo()
          Dim FunctionArray(2,2)
          {input all data into array}
          GetInfo = FunctionArray()
    End Function
```

Any Help i could get would be great as this is new to me.

Comment: Leave off the parentheses after `FunctionArray`. You probably also shouldn't name your variable `Array` in SubroutineA, since that is the name of a built-in function.

Answer (score 5):

Cheran Shunmugavel points to the right direction, but his explanation contains an ambiguety. To make it clear:

```
Sub SubroutineA()
      Dim Arr     ' <<<--- do not use parenthesis here and do not use
                  '        the reserved keyword "Array"
      Arr = GetInfo()
End Sub

Function GetInfo()
      Dim FunctionArray(2,2)
      ' {input all data into array}
      GetInfo = FunctionArray     ' <<<--- do not use parenthesis here
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain why this works?