# How can I return a dynamic array from within a function in VBS for later use outside the function?

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I've searched through a few websites and have not had any success in finding a solution that fits my needs.  I am using a function in VBScript to create two arrays, one based on a specified date range, and the other is a dynamic array based on the filenames at the location of interest.  I then compare the values in the two arrays and remove the duplicates from the main array, and check to see which values are weekdays.

So far all of that works.  **The difficulty I am having is being able to pass the "RangeArr()" array outside of the function**.  See my working code below:

```
FindMissingReports(TestPath)

Function FindMissingReports(Path)

Dim FileName, File
Dim RangeArr()
intSize = 0
For i = 0 to 7
    ReDim Preserve RangeArr(intSize)
    RangeArr(intSize) = Year(Date - i) & "-" & Month(Date - i) & "-" & Day(Date - i)
    intSize = intSize +1
Next
'
Dim FileArr()
intSize = 0
'
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Create the object used to display popup boxes
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Loop through all of the files in the "Path" directory.
For Each File in oFSO.getfolder(Path).Files
    'If the file name contains "Defect Report"
    If instr(File.Name, "Defect Report") <> 0 Then
        Set objFile = oFSO.GetFile(File)
        'Define the filename as a variable
        FileName = File.Name
        'Get the report date from the first 10 characters of the filename.
        FileDate = Left(FileName, 10)
        ReDim Preserve FileArr(intSize)
        FileArr(intSize) = FileDate
        intSize = intSize +1
    End If
Next
'
For i = 0 to UBound(FileArr)
    For j = 0 to UBound(RangeArr)
        If UBound(RangeArr) > UBound(FileArr) and UBound(FileArr) <> -1 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            If FileArr(i) = RangeArr(j) Then
                removalIndexFile = i
                For x = removalIndexFile to UBound(FileArr) -1
                    FileArr(x) = FileArr(x+1)
                Next
                ReDim Preserve FileArr(UBound(FileArr)-1)
                removalIndexRange = j
                For x = removalIndexRange to UBound(RangeArr) -1
                    RangeArr(x) = RangeArr(x+1)
                Next
                ReDim Preserve RangeArr(UBound(RangeArr)-1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
'
For i = 0 to UBound(RangeArr)
If IsWeekday(RangeArr(i)) Then
    MsgBox(RangeArr(i) & ".  It worked!  This is the only weekday report missing from the list.")
End If
Next
'
End Function

Function IsWeekday(theDate)
    IsWeekday = Weekday(theDate,vbMonday) <= 5
End Function
```

Comment: What is the point in posting the code that works? Show what is not working from your attempt to return the dynamic array from the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [returning a two dimensional array from a function in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562862/returning-a-two-dimensional-array-from-a-function-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBScript way to return something from a function is to assign that something to the function's name. Demo:

```
Option Explicit


' To return x from a function, assign x to the function's name
Function f(p)
  Select Case p 
    Case "Array()"
      f = Array("array via Array()")
    Case "FuncLikeSplit()"
      f = Split("func-returns-(dyn)-array")
    Case "DimReDimAssign"
      Dim tmp
      ReDim tmp(0)
      tmp(0) = "Dim-ReDim-Assign"
      f = tmp
    Case Else
      WScript.Echo "Error!"
  End Select
End Function

Dim a, p
' prove for each a: it's a dynamic array
For  Each p In Split("Array() FuncLikeSplit() DimReDimAssign")
     a = f(p)
     WScript.Echo p, TypeName(a), UBound(a), a(0)
     ReDim Preserve a(Ubound(a) + 1)
     a(UBound(a)) = "grownup"
     WScript.Echo UBound(a), a(UBound(a))
     WScript.Echo "----------------"
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 47042147.vbs
Array() Variant() 0 array via Array()
1 grownup
----------------
FuncLikeSplit() Variant() 0 func-returns-(dyn)-array
1 grownup
----------------
DimReDimAssign Variant() 0 Dim-ReDim-Assign
1 grownup
----------------
```

So:

```
FindMissingReports = RangeArr
```

at the end of the function, and:

```
Dim a : a = FindMissingReports(TestPath)
```

at the top level.

Comment: All that to say set the return value to the Functions name. Nothing surprises me anymore. You know, I could have posted that three hours ago but thought better if it as the OP hadn’t even attempted to return the array.